# Checking Range in Comma Separated Values [SQL Server 2008]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following structure

```
 ID FirstName LastName CollectedNumbers
 1      A       B       10,11,15,55
 2      C       D       101,132,111
```

I want a boolean value based on CollectedNumber Range. e.g. If CollectedNumbers are between 1 and 100 then True if Over 100 then False. Can anyone Suggest what would be best way to accomplish this. Collected Numbers won't be sorted always.

Comment: The "best way to accomplish this" would be to properly normalize the data, so you have another table, with one row per `id` and and `CollectNumber`.  SQL has a great method for storing lists.  It is called a table, not a character column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It so happens that you have a pretty simple way to see if values are 100 or over in the list.  If such a value exists, then there are at least *three* characters between the commas.  If the numbers are never more than 999, you could do:

```
select (case when ','+CollectedNumbers+',' not like '%,[0-9][0-9][0-9]%' then 1
             else 0
        end) as booleanflag
```

This happens to work for the break point of 100.  It is obviously not a general solution.  The best solution would be to use a junction table with one row per `id` and `CollectedNumber`.

Comment: +1 If you change condition to `not like '%,[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'` (without the last comma) it will work for all values more than 100, not only 3 characters.

Comment: @valex . . . That is a great observation.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a function, which will return true/False, in the database which will convert the string values(10,11,15,55) into a table and call that function in the Selection of the Query like this

```
Select 
    ID, FirstName, LastName, 
    dbo.fncCollectedNumbersResult(stringvalue) as Result 
from yourTableName
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest you can do is build a C# function and use the builtin sqlclr to load it as a custom function you can then call.

Inside the C# function, you can then sort your numbers and make simple logic to return your true/false.